# Is it weird that my eyes hurt more on my laptop than they do on my smart phone?

Tags: display

I can be on my Nexus 5 typing and doing different things and I'm fine. But when I get on my laptop, it just bothers my eyes after a while. (I have a Dell Inspiron 15.) The Nexus 5 is known for its vivid screen and powerful processor.

Why would my eyes NOT hurt on my smart phone? After all, it is smaller. Is it that the viewing technology (screen) is just so much more up-to-date on smart phones?

Comment: Most eye irritation I experience is due to lowered rate of blinking when focused on a computer. Perhaps you are more hyper-focused on your laptop than on your phone, and your eyes are becoming dry.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Nexus 5 have high quality IPS screen with high resolution. Your laptop doesn't, that's the issue, your eyes are getting tired faster.